# How does the size of conducting sphere affect the distribution of charge?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, charge

I am doing my homework. 
One question gives individual charges on two spheres. And asks what the resulting charge is on each after touching.

But one thing interest me is that in the answer key, it's explained that since the two spheres are equal in size, each sphere must contain exactly half the sum of their charges added up.

Why and how does size matter here?

Answer (score 2):

What matters is the surface of the object (in this case sphere). On the sphere a charge would distribute uniformly. In the situation that you described what matters is the relative size of the surfaces of two spheres. Since they are equal the charge on both of the them is the same (and hence is the half of the original charge).